# Find all sections while sections header table not present

Tags: linux, binaryfiles, gnu, elf

According to Learning Linux Binary Analysis by elfmaster sections header table can be not present in ELF file. How to find all sections in file when that haeder is not included?

Answer (score 0):

> How to find all sections in file when that haeder is not included?

How do you find money in an empty pocket? It's simply *not there*.

Likewise, once the section table is removed (which is perfectly legal to do to `ET_DYN` and `ET_EXEC` ELF files: sections are not used at runtime), the sections are simply *not present*.

You can try to *guess* where the section boundaries used to be, but you can't *find* sections.

Comment: Thanks for input from you. Unfortunately in elfmaster's book myself find contrary allegations, sections may still be present in while after section headers table has been stripped.